# i want to add space between my generated prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on unity2D game and im working on instantiating prefabs, im generating my prefabs in a good way but the problem is that i want a space between them when they are generated, i meant when prefabs are generating i want to add space between them in position x, there is my code:

```
public class WaveSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject[] easyWaves;
     public GameObject[] mediumWaves;
     public GameObject[] hardWaves;
     public GameObject Player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SpawnWave();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void SpawnWave()
    {
 float CharacSpeed = Player.GetComponent<charachter>().moveSpeed;
 float spacing = 0.1f;
        if(CharacSpeed < 11){

            Instantiate(easyWaves[Random.Range(0,easyWaves.Length)], new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y,0) , Quaternion.identity);


        }
        else if(CharacSpeed >= 11 && CharacSpeed < 14){

            Instantiate(mediumWaves[Random.Range(0,mediumWaves.Length)], new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x , gameObject.transform.position.y,0), Quaternion.identity);

      }
         else if(CharacSpeed >= 14){
             Instantiate(hardWaves[Random.Range(0,hardWaves.Length)], new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y,0), Quaternion.identity);

          }

    } 
}
```

any help please? notice that my prefabs are generating correctly, the problem is only on position x

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your code will only spawn a single prefab from one of your GameObject arrays.  What it does is:

- Look at the CharacSpeed
- Based on the CharacSpeed, instantiate a single randomly selected GameObject from either easyWaves, mediumWaves or hardWaves.

So, I'm not sure what you mean by spacing your prefabs since there is only one prefab spawned.

Try this:

```
public void SpawnWave()
{  
    GameObject[] selectedWaves = new GameObject[];
    float CharacSpeed = Player.GetComponent<charachter>().moveSpeed;  
    float spacing = 0.1f;

    if(CharacSpeed < 11){
        selectedWaves = easyWaves;
    }
    else if(CharacSpeed >= 11 && CharacSpeed < 14){
        selectedWaves = mediumWaves;
    }
    else if(CharacSpeed >= 14)
    {
         selectedWaves = hardWaves;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedWaves.Length; i++) {
        Instantiate(selectedWaves[Random.Range(0,selectedWaves.Length)], new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x + (spacing * i), gameObject.transform.position.y,0) , Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

You should then be able to adjust the amount of spacing by changing the `float spacing = 0.1f` value.

This assumes that you want to spawn as many prefabs as are contained in your GameObject arrays (and may want to spawn the same one multiple times).  If not, change `selectedWaves.Length` in the for loop to whatever number of prefabs you want spawned.

Comment: they r beign generated on the same position with this code and they start getting desorder, with my code prefabs are generating correctly, i don't know what's the problem, thank you anyway